# Python: Frequency Analysis of Sound Files

Tags: python, audio, wav, fft, gnuplot

I am generating some sound files that play tones at various frequencies with a certain number of harmonics.
Ultimately, these sounds will be played on a device with a small speaker.

I have the frequency response curve of the speaker and want to do the following in Python:

1. Plot the frequency spectrum of sound file. I need a take the FFT of the file and plot it with `gnuplot`
2. Apply a nonlinear transfer function based on the frequency response curve in the data sheet.
3. Plot the result after the function is applied.

Does anyone know :

- What the **simplest way** to do this would be?
- or of an **Application** (GNU/Linux based) that could do this for me?

Comment: SciPy's introduction includes doing an FFT and plotting the result: http://www.scipy.org/Getting_Started

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I know you didn't mention Pylab/Matplotlib, but it works. Here is an example (assumes single-channel signal):

```
x, fs, nbits = audiolab.wavread('schubert.wav')
audiolab.play(x, fs)
N = 4*fs    # four seconds of audio
X = scipy.fft(x[:N])
Xdb = 20*scipy.log10(scipy.absolute(X))
f = scipy.linspace(0, fs, N, endpoint=False)
pylab.plot(f, Xdb)
pylab.xlim(0, 5000)   # view up to 5 kHz

Y = X*H
y = scipy.real(scipy.ifft(Y))
```

Comment: No, I meant `H`. Sorry, I just skipped a bunch of steps because I'm lazy. If `h` is your impulse response, then `H = scipy.fft(h)`. In item 2 of your question, you are given a transfer function frequency response directly, so that would be `H`.

Comment: BTW, 20*log10 shows the pressure of the acoustic wave. For sound intensity, it should rather be 10*log10.

Answer (score 4):

you can use numpy and matPlotLib. Something like the code below:

```
spectrum = numpy.fft.fft(signal)
frequencies = numpy.fft.fftfreq(len(spectrum))
pylab.plot(frequencies,spectrum)
pylab.show()
```

That will show a graph of the fft spectrum.

Answer (score 0):

[scipy](http://www.scipy.org/Getting_Started) has an FFT and hooks nicely into gnuplot. You should be able to use the [signal](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/signal.html) module to do the math.