# python parsing audio in stream

Tags: python, audio, stream, analyzer

I want to analyze the input stream of my audio-in with python.
The contains data from a radio reciever.

Sometimes the radio signal contains a block of 5 tones. I need to analyze the stream for this blocks.
They look like:

[image: Principle]

The frequencys look like this:

```
number       1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    0    R
Frequency/Hz 1060 1160 1270 1400 1530 1670 1830 2000 2200 2400 2600
```

What is the best way in python to implement this?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4315989/python-frequency-analysis-of-sound-files

Comment: Can you please clarify exactly what you are asking? Are you asking for a way to analyze a block? If so what do you want to analyze about it? Or are you trying to identify when these blocks are taking place?

Comment: i need to analyze when they take place, and then i need to get the number which was sent, eg. 88022.

Comment: Hi my first answer was too complex because I missed some details you provided above, in case you read it already, see my updated response below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store all your data for a short time into a 70 ms buffer, and constantly take the FFT searching for a spike at each frequency you're searching for. Collect 5 numbers in a row to complete the sequence. Each time you collect a value, wait 70 ms before you collect the next number.